# Gatsby - Trying to render image with URL - Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

This is my code:

```
const Image = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
    facebook {
      posts {
        data {
          full_picture
        }
      }
    }
  }
  `)

  // console.log(data.facebook.posts.data)

  const images = data.facebook.posts.data;

  const sources = images.filter(function(img) {
    if (img.full_picture == null) {
      return false;
    }
    return true
  }).map(function (img) {
    return (
      <Img src={img.full_picture} />
    )
  })

  return (
    <div>
      {sources}
    </div>
  )
}
```

The error I'm receiving is

> `"TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"`

If I remove the HTML from the return (Img) then it will display all the URLs on the page, but as soon as I add the Img tag it doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the images are not loaded when you try to display it in `Img` you could do :

`<Img src={img?img.full_picture:''} />`

This should help.

Comment: No luck. I believe it's there because If I remove the <Img /> it displays all of the urls on the screen.

Comment: @TomHanks is it a custom component or are you using the native <img/> tag with a capital I?

Comment: Okay, I got it to work by changing the <Img> to <img>, but now it's not using Img from gatsby-image.

Comment: Yes <Img/> is invalid unless you have a custom component. Then what image is it using? its coming from somewhere right

Comment: Yes, its a component I'm importing from gatsby-image.